# Android SoftKeyboard: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" Not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

Before asking this question : @Nagekeeran Piraba & me are working same company.I asked this question on behalf of her. I am new to Android & This Site also

I have List of product in TableLayout which contain EditText. Once the user click on  EditText, Key borad will appear :

http://hotfile.com/dl/130483171/c278c87/key1.png.html

**Image:1**

After few seconds This screen will change like this :
http://hotfile.com/dl/130483238/123302a/key2.png.html

**Image 2**

This is running on Emulator.When I run on real device.Its hide the scroll view , I couldn't see my tableLayout's product.

**I need keyboard as figure no :1. Don't want like 2 image**

This is my Code :

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/wallpaper">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:orientation="vertical">
   <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/orderTopLayer"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        ..................
        </TableLayout>


  <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/orderPriceLayer"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        ............
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>

    <!--  Product List part -->     
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_thumb" android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_track" android:scrollbarSize="5dp" android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0" android:fillViewport="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_weight="1" android:scrollbars="vertical">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="396dp">
            <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TableLayout  android:stretchColumns="*" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_margin="2pt" android:layout_marginTop="0dp"  android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                    </TableLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp">
  ....................
    </LinearLayout>
  <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/pageHeader"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp">
        ........................


 </RelativeLayout>
 <!-- Footer -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        ......
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**In Emulator show at least that selected row.But in Real device It didn't show the any of EditText or Table row.It hided by keyboard.**

I don't know this is way of asking question.If its wrong please forgive me.Our serious issue.That's why I asked this question on behalf of her.

Please tell me any solution.

I have gone through article/question here.
[Soft Keyboard Overlapping with EditText Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559367/soft-keyboard-overlapping-with-edittext-field)
[When the soft keyboard appears, it makes my EditText field lose focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615436/when-the-soft-keyboard-appears-it-makes-my-edittext-field-lose-focus)

Please help me

**I am really sorry I can't upload image here.I don't have permission**

Thanks.

Comment: Please refer this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240165/how-to-scroll-my-layout-when-setting-androidwindowsoftinputmode-adjustpan

may be it helps you.