# How to scroll my layout when setting android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"?

Tags: android, android-layout

My activity have a top bar and a bottom bar. the space between topbar and bottom bar i have a linearlayout with several edittext views inside. Because i don't want my layout resize every time the softkeyboard show up, so i set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" for my activity in manifest. But when the softkeyboard is openned, i want to scroll down to select another edittext to input, it's not allow me do that. Im only able to select the edittext at bottom when i close the softkeyboard. That's very annoying and inconvenient.
How can i get both scrollview and ajustpan mode for softkeyboard work well together?

Please help me out. thanks you so much.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I dont like to do the coding you did to "fake it"... hmm

Comment: so far this solution has worked well, i also looked for an alternative that is simpler. hope someone else will share a better workaround for this issue.

Comment: But this solution hides buttons, when the soft keyboard is shown. But depending on screen resolution etc, the button may not need to be hidden, right?

Comment: this solution won't resize your view when softkeyboard show up, and you can scroll your view to see the controls that are hided by softkeyboard. i'm sorry that i dont understand your case so much.

Answer (score 4):

At last, i find out a workaround for my problem, so i want to share for someone maybe get the same problem in future. A brief description of my layout as following:

```
<myRelativeLayout>
<topbar.../>
<myscrollView>
    <linearLayout>
        //all stuff controls:editview,textview,....
    </linearLayout>
</myscrollView>
<bottombar.../>
```

i create custom class myRelativeLayout extend RelativeLayout

```
public class myRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout{

public interface OnRelativeLayoutChangeListener {
    void onLayoutPushUp();
    void onLayoutPushDown();
}

private OnRelativeLayoutChangeListener layoutChangeListener;
public myRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int proposedheight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    final int actualHeight = getHeight();

    if (actualHeight > proposedheight){
        // Keyboard is shown
        layoutChangeListener.onLayoutPushUp();
    } else if(actualHeight < proposedheight){
        // Keyboard is hidden
        layoutChangeListener.onLayoutPushDown();
    }       
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

public void setLayoutChangeListener(OnRelativeLayoutChangeListener layoutChangeListener) {
    this.layoutChangeListener = layoutChangeListener;
}

public OnRelativeLayoutChangeListener getLayoutChangeListener() {
    return layoutChangeListener;
}
```

}

And in my activity , i just set setLayoutChangeListener for myRelativeLayout to hide bottombar when softkeyboard show up and display bottombar when softkeyboard hide:

```
myRlayout.setLayoutChangeListener(new OnRelativeLayoutChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLayoutPushUp() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myBottombar.setVisibility(View.GONE);//in my case i need to setVisibility(View.GONE) to bottombar in order for this bar is not displayed when softkeyboard show up.
        }

        @Override
        public void onLayoutPushDown() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myBottombar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);// redisplay myBottombar when keyboard is closed.

        }
    });
```

Dont forget set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" for activity.
Hope this useful for someone got the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for this, however, isnt there a way to do it without the additional coding that "fakes" the functionality we want?

Answer (score 1):

put those `EditText` in a `ScrollView` like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: i'm not ask about how to make a layout in xml, i'm want to know how to scroll my layout when i set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" for my activity.