# Understanding android text input and soft keyboard

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, rhomobile

When user selects input field, keyboard comes up but the input field text is right on top of the virtual keyboard.

Problem gets worse when it is a textarea because keyboard wants to focus on the first line only not the entire textarea box.

In my AndroidManifest.xml I tried changing android:windowSoftInputMode='adjustPan' but did not  help.

[image]

EDIT -------------------

Using Rhomobile, Jquery Mobile and iScroll

Form is in a data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="inline" div tag to make it stick to the bottom of the view.

```
<input class="imInput>" name="im[the_message]" type="text" maxlength="100"/>
```

No matter what I do the keyboard lines up with the bottom of the text.  I have tried making line-height larger, padding, etc.  nothing works.

How Can I make the keyboard line-up to the bottom of the field?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html) about the various input methods to see what would work best for your app. Otherwise it is hard to say what is going on without understanding your app better with code, etc. If not that, than [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559367/soft-keyboard-overlapping-with-edittext-field) seems to be somewhat similar to the problem that you are having.

Comment: Hi, koopaking3 I tried those articles but didn't work.  I did edit manifest.xml and added android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" but the keyboard is still not lining up to the fields. :(

Comment: Sorry, didn't see you were using Rhomobile, Jquery Mobile and iScroll. I have no experience with those. Good luck!