# EditText didn't move enough space when Soft Keyboard popped up

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have similar issue with: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559367/soft-keyboard-overlapping-with-edittext-field/4600618#4600618), I have set:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

but the bottom of the `EditText` is overlapped by the keyboard.  My:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Anybody know the reason?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to declared in your activity manifest

```
  <activity
        android:name=".activityname"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Hello Nepster, thank you for your response, but when i tried your code, the keyboard totally overlapped the edittext.

Comment: put layout inside a ScrollView and also try android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" one by one