# up the page 20dip when keyboard appear

Tags: android

i want to up the layout approx 20dip when i click on edit text keyboard appear so my submitt button hide below key board so i want to up layout approx 20 dip ,n also i cant set scroll i have image on background...so how to up whole layout with background when my keyboard launch ...thanks

my xml is for creating layout for that screen.....

Answer (score 0):

There's a very similar question on StackOverflow..

[Layout becomes invisible, when keyboard pops up.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1925428/999207)

Hope this helps!!

Sorry, I had to post this as an answer, rather than comment on the question..

Comment: i use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  in corresponding activity tag in manifest file but does not work.means button is not going up when keyboard launch

Comment: try using "adjustResize" instead of "adjustPan". this will cause the whole layout to resize, as a result of which the button will come up. If you introduce scroll views in the layout, you might face some problems with the resizing, i guess.

Comment: sometimes, the resize may not happen if there is not enough space in the layout to fit all the Views and the IME..